# Problema ao passar Bean polulada para controller e inserir no BD utilizando Java com Spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Gostaria que pudessem me ajudar com esse problema que está ocorrendo na minha aplicação.

Segue abaixo o codigo:

```
 package br.com.estoque.Controller;


 import java.util.Map;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.estoque.Dao.CategoriaProdutoDao;
import br.com.estoque.Dao.ProdutoDao;
import br.com.estoque.Modelo.Produto;

@Controller
public class ProdutoController {

@RequestMapping("produtoForm")
public ModelAndView entradaForm(){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    CategoriaProdutoDao dao = new CategoriaProdutoDao();
    mav.setViewName("produtos/frmCadastroProduto");
    mav.addObject("lista",dao.listar());
    mav.addObject("produto",new Produto());
    return mav;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/inserirProduto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("produto") Produto produto){
    ProdutoDao dao = new ProdutoDao();      
    dao.adiciona(produto);
    return "produtos/frmCadastroProduto";
}


}
```

Minha frmCadastroProduto

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <form:form action="inserirProduto" method="post" modelAttribute="produto">

            <table border="0">   

            <tr>
        <td><form:label path="descricao">Nome Produto</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="descricao" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="categoriaProduto">Selecione a categoria de produto</form:label></td>
        <td><form:select path="categoriaProduto">
            <form:option value=" - " label="--Please Select"></form:option>
            <form:options items="${lista}" itemValue="cdCategoriaProduto" itemLabel="descricao"/>
        </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tela de erro que está me voltando...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Luiz, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Qual é a URL do erro 400?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Estoque/inserirProduto  é essa aqui!, se precisar de mais detalhes pra entender o problema eu mando!!

Comment: Comparei com um sistema que tenho aqui e aparentemente está tudo certo, exceto que não posso verificar suas configurações. Chega a executar o método `inserirProduto()`? Se passar por ali, provavelmente o problema está no redirecionamento ao final. Você tme um tiles configurado para `ok`?

Comment: E remova essa anotação `@ResponseBody`, ela é geralmente usada para retornar Json. Você tem outro cadastro que funciona com `POST`?

Comment: eu ja removi `@ResponseBody` , eu possuo sim uma JSP chamada ok . o Metodo adiciona() não chega a ser executado, pois nao me retorna uma msg no console que coloquei na execução do metodo.  Se precisar de mais informações a respeito das minhas configurações eu posso postar aqui!!! eu estou meio desesperado pois preciso entregar esse sistema até o final do ano, e essa é só a primeira tela de cadastro... obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: se voce puder me passar como o controller deste seu sistema que vc comparou ficou, seria de grande ajuda tb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema parece ser causado porque você tem um tipo "complexo" `CategoriaProduto` como atributo de `Produto`sendo mapeado para um campo de valor simples, i.e., a"combo" cujo valor das opções é baseado `cdCategoriaProduto`.

Subentendi isso pelo trecho `produto.getCategoriaProduto().getCdCategoriaProduto()`.

A não ser que tenha feito a configuração de um *binder* em algum outro lugar, o Spring vai ver que a informação submetida na requisição não é compatível com o seu *model* recebido por parâmetro, explicando então o erro 400 de que a *requisição está sintaticamente incorreta*.

Qual a solução?

## 1. Use um atributo "Simples"

Crie um atributo `codigoCategoria` do tipo String ou numérico para receber o valor do formulário ao invés de usar uma classe sua.

Se precisar recuperar outras informações da categoria, use o código para recuperar o valor da sessão ou do banco de dados.

## 2. Crie um *Editor*

O Spring permite configurar uma classe especial para fazer a conversão automática durante o *binding* do *request* com o seu *model*.

Veja um exemplo ([que peguei do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138760/1683070)):

```
public class GroupEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    private final GroupService groupService;

    public GroupEditor(GroupService groupService){
        this.groupService= groupService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      Group group = groupService.getById(Integer.parseInt(text));
      setValue(group);
    }
}
```

O método `setAsText` é usado durante o *request*. Ele vai receber o valor do campo (o código, no seu caso) e então você deve recuperar o objeto `CategoriaProduto` correspondente.

Note que esse `groupService` do exemplo seria um *bean* responsável por buscar o valor no banco de dados, por exemplo.

Finalmente, você configura o Spring para usar a classe acima no seu `Controller` da seguinte forma:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)     {
      binder.registerCustomEditor(Group.class, new GroupEditor(groupService));
}
```

Faça uma adaptação desse código para as suas classes.

Comment: Sera que voce poderia me explicar melhor a opção numero 1 de como resolver o problema... eu alterei o meu controller em relação a como estou desponibilizando os meus models para a JSP, porem eu não entendi onde devo criar a variavel string para que não ocorra o erro. Obrigado utluiz

Comment: @LuizFernandoAugusto Mude o tipo do atributo de `CategoriaProduto` para uma `String`. Aí o Spring vai conseguir preencher o código. Aí se vc precisar de outros dados do produto, pode recuperar novamente do banco. Esta é a solução mais simples de fazer e explicar.

Comment: Consegui criar a classe editora!! resolvi este problema Obrigadoo!

Answer (score 0):

Este é o seu metodo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inserirProduto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("produto") Produto produto){
//sua logica aqui
}
```

Note que você está enviado via post, então deveria ser assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/inserirProduto,""}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@RequestBody Produto produto){
// sua logica aqu
}
```

Quando vem da tela o spring popular para você, como você esta usando post então tem que usar `@RequestBody`, note também o uso das `{}` no `@RequestMapping`.

Assim vai funcionar corretamente.